# How can I print the first result of a search sequence for each iteration?

Tags: database, perl, bioinformatics, bioperl

How can I print the first occurrence of a protein sequence? For this query I get four results and I want only the first.

```
use Bio::DB::GenBank;
use Bio::DB::Query::GenBank;

$query     = "LEGK";
$query_obj = Bio::DB::Query::GenBank->new(
    -db    => 'protein',
    -query => $query
);

$gb_obj = Bio::DB::GenBank->new;

$stream_obj = $gb_obj->get_Stream_by_query( $query_obj );

while ( $seq_obj = $stream_obj->next_seq ) {

    # do something with the sequence object
    print
        ">$query", ' ',
        $seq_obj->display_id, ' ',
        $seq_obj->desc, "\n",
        $seq_obj->seq[, '\n';
```

That `while` loop should look like this

```
while ( $seq_obj = $stream_obj->next_seq ) {

    # do something with the sequence object
    print $seq_obj->display_id, "\t", $seq_obj->length, "\n";
}
```

Comment: This will not compile. Please post enough code that it can be run without fixing syntax errors, unless those are part of the question. This creates additional work for anyone trying to help you! Also, please do put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Well I've posted an answer. If it's not useful, please try and explain what you're looking for in more detail. This is a perl forum, and I for one am not a geneticist ;)

Comment: @MTG: Please don't edit your question so as to make nonsense of any answers or comments that have already been posted. I have restored your malformed Perl code and added your new code as an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see with your snippet is that it does not compile.
Put `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of all your perl programs.
This will alert you to syntax errors.

I do not know much about biology, however, you are iterating over sequence objects, but then making a rather strange call with `$seq_obj->seq[,'\n'`

First of all, to call a function, use `()`, not `[]`, `[]` indicates a reference to an array. Secondly, `seq` seems to be used to set or get a sequence value, and I do not see how `'\n'` would be a valid value.

So

```
while ($seq_obj = $stream_obj->next_seq) {
    print join(' ', $seq_obj->display_id, $seq_obj->desc)."\n"; # or use 'say'
    print $seq_obj->seq() . "\n";
}
```

should print all sequences. To get just the first, simply don't iterate through all results ( That's how I understood your question ):

replace the while (){} with:

```
my $first_seq_obj = $stream_obj->next_seq;
print join(' ', $first_seq_obj->display_id, $first_seq_obj->desc)."\n"; # or use 'say'
print $first_seq_obj->seq() . "\n";
```